# maxed CPU performance - stack all tasks or aim for less than 100%?

Tags: performance, cpu, multitasking

I have 12 tasks to run on an octo-core machine. All tasks are CPU intensive and each will max out a core.

Is there a theoretical reason to avoid stacking tasks on a maxed out core (such as overhead, swapping across tasks) or is it faster to queue everything?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 12 tasks? Does your design use 12 long running threads, or do you have 12 different types of functionality that you need to dispatch.

Comment: Also what OS are you using? What kind of workload? Graphics?

Comment: Why not try variations and see what happens.

Comment: I am parallelizing a process that performs SQL queries on a text database and parses dates that are expressed in different languages and in different manners. It has been split across 12 applets, one for each months. I could launch some of them and wait for the first to that terminate before launching another. I currently launch all at once. (no hardware problem -- the CPU stays reasonably cool)

Comment: Depending on language and OS there are things like Intel Thread Profiler

Comment: Also how many records

Comment: Also how many records are you retrieving per query. Also think about culling the list, you may have a lot of duplicates, that will depend on the precision of the datetime value. Maybe use a hashmap of some kind.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I believe that the code is reasonably efficient. The question is more for me to learn if it is worth investing the time to manage concurrency, or better not to bother because the computer's architecture is better equipped to handle these situations.

Answer (score 1):

Task switching is a waste of CPU time. Avoid it if you can.

Whatever the scheduler timeslice is set to, the CPU will waste its time every time slice by going into the kernel, saving all the registers, swapping the memory mappings and starting the next task. Then it has to load in all its CPU cache, etc.

Much more efficient to just run one task at a time.

Things are different of course if the tasks use I/O and aren't purely compute bound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's called queueing theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory. There are many different models https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Queueing_theory for a range of different problems I'd suggest you scan them and pick the one most applicable to your workload then go and read up on how to avoid the worst outcomes for that model, or pick a different, better, model for dispatching your workload.

Although the graph at this link https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:StochasticQueueingQueueLength.png applies to Traffic it will give you an idea of what is happening to response times as your CPU utilisation increases. It shows that you'll reach an inflection point after which things get slower and slower.

More work is arriving than can be processed with subsequent work waiting longer and longer until it can be dispatched.

The more cores you have the further to the right you push the inflection point but the faster things go bad after you reach it.

I would also note that unless you've got some really serious cooling in place you are going to cook your CPU. Depending on it's design it will either slow itself down, making your problem worse, or you'll trigger it's thermal overload protection.

So a simplistic design for 8 cores would be, 1 thread to manage things and add tasks to the work queue and 7 threads that are pulling tasks from the work queue. If the tasks need to be performed within a certain time you can add a TimeToLive value so that they can be discarded rather than executed needlessly. As you are almost certainly running your application in an OS that uses a pre-emptive threading model consider things like using processor affinity where possible because as @Zan-Lynx says task/context switching hurts. Be careful not to try to build your OS'es thread management again as you'll probably wind up in conflict with it.

Comment: If you can't run all cores under full load (**including AVX**!) for 24 hours then your computer is built wrong. Fix its cooling.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr: cache thrash is Bad

You have a dozen tasks. Each will have to do a certain amount of work.

At an app level they each processed a thousand customer records or whatever. That is fixed, it is a constant no matter what happens on the hardware.

At the the language level, again it is fixed, C++, java, or python will execute a fixed number of app instructions or bytecodes. We'll gloss over gc overhead here, and page fault and scheduling details.

At the assembly level, again it is fixed, some number of x86 instructions will execute as the app continues to issue new instructions.

But you don't care about **how many** instructions, you only care about **how long** it takes to execute those instructions. Many of the instructions are reads which MOV a value from RAM to a register. Think about how long that will take. Your computer has several components to implement the memory hierarchy - which ones will be involved? Will that read hit in L1 cache? In L2? Will it be a miss in last-level cache so you wait (for *tens* or *hundreds* of cycles) until RAM delivers that cache line? Did the virtual memory reference miss in RAM, so you wait (for *milliseconds*) until SSD or Winchester storage can page in the needed frame? You think of your app as issuing N reads, but you might more productively think of it as issuing 0.2 * N cache misses. Running at a different multi-programming level, where you issue 0.3 * N cache misses, could make elapsed time quite noticeably longer.

Every workload is different, and can place larger or smaller demands on memory storage. But every level of the memory hierarchy depends on caching to some extent, and higher multi-programming levels are guaranteed to impact cache hit rates. There are network- and I/O-heavy workloads where very high multi-programming levels absolutely make sense. But for CPU- and memory-intensive workloads, when you benchmark elapsed times **you may find that less is more**.